# undefined reference errors when cross-compiling with openssl library

Tags: c, linux, openssl

The target is a beaglebone black running debian

The host is a PC running Ubuntu 13.04

I have code that compiles OK on the target.

```
gcc main.c -lssl
```

On the host I am using the linaro gcc compiler.

```
CC=gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.07-1_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

If I copy /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libssl.so from the target to myLibs on the host,then try

```
 $CC main.c -L /myLibs/ -lssl
```

I get:

```
main.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `SHA256_Init'

main.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `SHA256_Update'

main.c:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `SHA256_Final'

libssl.so: undefined reference to `BIO_pop@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I copied libcrypto.so and libz.so from the target to the host.
Now
    $CC main.c -L /myLibs/ -lssl -lcrypto -lz

terminates with no errors.